# Ng new error with Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I'm trying to start a new project in Angular and when I do the command ng new projectName in my console, I get the follow error:

```
npm WARN deprecated istanbul-lib-hook@1.2.1: 1.2.0 should have been a major 
version bump
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: istanbul@^0.4.5

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jmarques\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08- 
08T18_17_43_246Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

And when I try to do the command npm install, it returns the same error e don't install node_modules.

Version:
 - Node 10.8.0 
 - npm 6.0.1
 - ng 6.1.2

Comment: You should check your npm config with `npm config get`, and check if repository is equal to the official one.

Comment: trichetriche, thanks for your answer. I verify and my repository was different from the official repository, so I reconfigured, realized the npm install again and then get no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing and deleting your node_modules, then clean cache 
`npm cache verify --force`
then reinstall using npm install.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer Taranjit, I deleted my node_module from AppData/Roaming/node_modules, installed angular/cli again. But still getting this error. When I execute the command ng new projectName, I get the error and the process stop without creating node_modules folder inside project folder.

Comment: try this then, 

npm remove @angular/cli
npm cache verify --force
npm install @angular/cli -g
npm install @angular/cli

Why i'm suggesting this, is because could be an issue with the cli installation itself. Uninstall, clean cache and re-install it. I thought you were npm installing in a new project, if you are creating one with the cli try this.

Comment: Taranjit, I did exactly what you said and still get the same error. Then I tried to start a new project in another pc, and it works perfectly. I don't know what's happening with this pc but if I start in other pc I get the archives normally and start the project normally. This is annoying, but for now is the best solution that I had.

Comment: I think it's your install of angular or some modules that's messing up, you have to completely wipe and remove any traces and re-install.

Comment: Taranjit, thanks for your answer again. I checked my npm config, and then I discovered that my repository was different from the official repository, so I reconfigured, did the npm install command again and then got no errors. The project starts normally. Thanks so much for your support and attention.